# New command doesn't work the same as in-line code

Tags: macros

I have a feeling that this is a profoundly stupid question but I cannot seem to solve it myself.

I am trying to write an own macro to create a boxed paragraph.  The code works fine in-line but when I try to define the command it just creates a small box in the same place that I wrote the command.  My codes are below.  I am pretty much a complete newbie at this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{Inline this works perfectly.}}

\newcommand{\note}{\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{}}}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In

```
\newcommand{\note}{\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{}}}
```

The content of the parbox is always specified by `{}` so empty.

```
\note{hello}
```

will make an empty box from `\note` before seeing `hello`.

You want `hello` to be an argument of `\note` so

```
\newcommand{\note}[1]{\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}}}
```

Comment: And that's called a *quick response*! -- At the velocity of light! `:-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works beautifully.  Much appreciated!

Comment: @MaraJade `\newcommand{\note}[1]{\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}{#1}}}` is probably better. I’d throw in an additional `\noindent` too.

Comment: Yes do as @Qrrbrbirlbel says, I addressed the programming question about how to define a macro with arguments but `\newcommand{\note}[1]{\noindent\fbox{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\rel‌​ax}{#1}}}` is a better definition in this case as otherwise the box will not fit on the line as the inner box is already full width and then outer box has padding and a rule on either side, and TeX may add paragraph indentation at the start.